# Nunit test on linq to sql resultset in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tdd, nunit

I have a model which contains a link to sql query that fetches information from my db then I loop it out in my view which renders a partial with the resultset in a table. Quite simple and straightforward. Although as I'm really struggling to get better at doing TDD I want to have a test for this. Bare in mind that if you  find a test that forces me to rethink my design that's just fine. Tests should help you see flaws in your designpatterns. I will post some of the code below of my model, and partial:

```
public class ApplicationModel
{
    public static DeployEntities DeployEntities = new DeployEntities();

    public static IQueryable<Application> GetApplicationList()
    {
        var applications = DeployEntities.Applications.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name);
        return applications.AsQueryable<Application>().Distinct();
    }
}


@{  
  foreach (var a in Deploy.Models.ApplicationModel.GetApplicationList())
                    {      
                <tr id="applications">
                    <td class="row-heading">
                        <p class="pseudo">@a.Name</p>  
                    </td> 
                    <td class="insert-col">
                    <div class="number-insert">
                        <p>Deploy Number</p>
                        <span class="count"></span>
                    </div>
```

So any thoughts on how I could go about with a test for this. I'm using MVC3 as you can see from the Razor syntax, and Entity Framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although as I'm really struggling to get better at doing TDD I want to have a test for this.

The following line ruins your model:

```
public static DeployEntities DeployEntities = new DeployEntities();
```

A static hardcoded dependency => impossible to unit test your model in isolation.

In order to weaken the coupling between your DAL and model you could introduce an abstraction:

```
public interface IApplicationRepository
{
    IQueryable<Application> GetApplications();
}
```

and then your model could use constructor injection:

```
public class ApplicationModel
{
    private readonly IApplicationRepository _repository;
    public ApplicationModel(IApplicationRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public static IQueryable<Application> GetApplicationList()
    {
        var applications = _repository.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name);
        return applications.AsQueryable<Application>().Distinct();
    }
}
```

Now in a unit test you could use a mocking framework such as Rhino Mocks or Moq to mock this repository and set expectations on it and be able to unit test the GetApplicationList method in isolation.

Comment: Thank you on that. I was thinking of introducing an interface though I wanted to improve this incrementally as I proceeded with the application. Although for the purpose of testing it easy you are right. Thanks.

Comment: However I still need to initalize an object of the Entity connection string to be able to query the database. In the code you submitted this is not provided. How would you go about with that? Would you do it in the interface or in the model??

Comment: @user1056170, you could use a dependency injection framework for this. Ninject is one example.

Comment: yes I was thinking about Ninject. Do you have any good resources on how to set it up with an MVC3 project using Entity Framework? You let MvcApplication in global.asax derive from NinjectHttpApplication right?! Thanks.

Comment: @user1056170, you may take a look at NerdDinner.

Comment: Darin, I did not find the NerdDinner example. I decided to go with the NinjectMvc3 version which gives me a appstart_folder with the ninject class. Do you have any good suggestions on how to apply the connection string. Where should it be declared? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model View Controller pattern, the part that gets unit tested is the controller. So in your case you would write a unit test for your controller function.

The should check if it gets all Applications returned, order by name and without duplicates.

How your view renders this information is outside the scope of this unit test.

Off course you could look at Coded UI Tests. Those tests check if your UI shows the correct data and responds correctly to user events.